# Is is possible to use non-pip-installable modules on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, mashape

I really want to use the Mashape python module in an app I have on Heroku. https://github.com/Mashape/mashape-python-client-library

However I've tried `pip install mashape` but I can't install it that way so I can't put it in my pip requirements.txt for Heroku to install when I deploy my application.

Is there another way around this? And in general is there a way for a Heroku app to use python modules that aren't installable via pip (like build from source instead)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably two ways for you to use mashape.

The first is to include mashape as part of your project and make sure that the `mashape` directory is in the `python path` in your project directory.  In this way, you can `import mashape` as usual.

The second way is to fork mashape and write a simple `setup.py` file for mashape in your own fork.  And then, without needing to uploading mashape into pypi, you can still install it using the `setup.py` you wrote and pushed up into your own forked github repo, via pip using something like:

```
`pip install -e git+git://github.com/YourFork/mashape-python-client-library.git#egg=mashape`
```

where `YourFork` is your github user id.

Comment: Does this also work if the python modules with shared (.so) objects that could like to other libraries on my computer?